# How do I install Nautilus-Elementary?

Tags: 10.10, package-management, ppa, nautilus-elementary

I've added the am-monkeyd PPA and upgraded my system. Yet, there's no sign of elementary in my fresh Maverick RC install. Have I done anything wrong?

The PPA upgrades the default nautilus package and there is no separate "nautilus-elementary" package as of now.

Now, there are three versions listed in the package properties:

```
1:2.32.0-0ubuntu1-ppa1 (maverick); 
1:2.32.0-0ubuntu5~ppa5 (maverick); 
1:2.32.0-0ubuntu1 (maverick);
```

Anything you can make out from this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From examining the [ppa](http://ppa.launchpad.net/am-monkeyd/nautilus-elementary-ppa/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/) itself `1:2.32.0-0ubuntu5~ppa140` looks to be the right version.

Did you try `apt-cache policy nautilus` to see if the ppa is correctly listed in package sources ?

Comment: Thank you very much! That's it. There's an other PPA which provides (the traditional) nautilus packages. Now that I've identified that PPA, I'll try purging it. This should definitely help. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I am happy that we could get a problem solved in less than an hour with 2 remote people collaborating... stackexchange never caeases to amaze me ...

Comment: That's it! I've purged the PPA and I have nautilus elementary now! I marked your answer as my answer of choice. Can't thank you more! :)

Comment: Yeah! Great site, this. :)

Comment: Thanks for the detective work. I filed a bug against it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautilus-elementary/+bug/657360

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. And BTW, the PPA (evidently) given the greater preference as the package source is "http://ppa.launchpad.net/erik-b-andersen/rgba-gtk/ubuntu/ maverick/main". I purged it and now have Nautilus elementary. And I second that statement of yours, regarding the "upgrade wars". :)

Comment: In fairness to the package author, it appears to result from a design limitation in the Gnome desktop (lack of choice of) file manager. See the bug report I noted above for detail.

Answer (score 6):

Adding the PPA only lists the source as a place to get packages

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nautilus-elementary
```

is what you need to actually install the package `nautilus-elementary`.

### added in response to comment

While I can't say much about the author's choice in naming a package fork, it appears as if his intention is for you to [add his PPA and upgrade](https://answers.launchpad.net/nautilus-elementary/+question/128553).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:am-monkeyd/nautilus-elementary-ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I'm guessing that this choice by "ammonkey" will lead to upgrade wars with the standard Ubuntu `nautilus` package at some point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response, but there is no package like nautilus-elementary. The nautilus package in the PPA upgrades the default nautilus instead of listing it as a separate package. I got the following output.

Comment: srinivasg@srinivasg-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install nautilus-elementary
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nautilus-elementary

Comment: Absolutely. And I've done all that already, to no avail. :)

Comment: If the package creator can't help you, I sure can't. Good luck.